# ENV variables are not set for test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I have a test database set like this in `database.yml`:

```
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: database_test
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  username:  <%= ENV['PG_USERNAME']%>
  password: <%= ENV['PG_PASSWORD']%>
```

I use `spring` gem for running tests (although this is not important as the issue occurs without using it as well)

The issue is that every time I run a `bundle exec rspec spec/` I get an error `no password supplied (PG::ConnectionBad)`:

```
/.bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize': fe_sendauth: no password supplied (PG::ConnectionBad)
```

And I need to change it manually to:

```
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: database_test
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  username:  postgres
  password: postgres
```

In order for it to work.

I have set variables in `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PG_USERNAME="postgres"
export PG_PASSWORD="postgres"
```

The strange is that in `development` mode it all **working fine** when I use the same structure as in `test`:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: database_dev
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  username:  <%= ENV['PG_USERNAME']%>
  password: <%= ENV['PG_PASSWORD']%>
```

What is the problem with my `test` environment and how to fix it in order for it to automatically use `ENV['PG_USERNAME']` like in development mode?

Comment: It sounds like when spring runs, it runs in a different environment to your regular user.  Put some simple logging in one of the first test files to run (that happens before the db config is loaded), saying something like `puts "whoami = #{\`whoami\`.inspect}"` and `puts "ENV = #{ENV.inspect}"`

Comment: If you are on mac OS X, try to put it in your `.bash_profile` instead of in your bashrc. Also, I'll post an answer for you below.

Comment: There is a tag - `ubuntu`, so I am using ubuntu

Comment: @MaxWilliams What do you mean by `that happens before the db config is loaded` - once any test is run it runs the database config first? There is nothing before which I could use. Also, it is not related to `spring` gem. I have noted in the question, is is happening even without that gem.

Comment: What do you see if you open a new terminal tab and type `echo $PG_USERNAME`?

Comment: There's always something that runs before loading the database - eg in your `config/environments/test.rb` file

Comment: Hmm, I see a "postgres" in both cases - but only when I run `bundle exec rspec spec/`, but not when I run it with spring - `bundle exec spring rspec spec/`. It seems it issue with spring after all. (although `test.rb` didn't run before the password issue when using spring)

Answer (score 0):

I proposed a quickfix in the comments, but I'd suggest to use the excellent [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) gem for configuration loading depending on your configuration. It would incidentally solve your current problem.

Comment: What root cause have you identified which made you suggest using new gem? I can't adding randomly gems and hoping it will work. I would like to solve it without quick fixes and also this would require me to change some additional code in my app as well

Comment: P.S. Moving to `.bash_profile` doesn't help, although it should be there in any-case :/